# Is Revelation a good substitute for a self-destruct device?

Tags: uplink

Over the course of the game, you get access to a virus called Revelation that can be used to destroy target systems (or rather to disable them for a while). Should you ever be traced and have the authorities break into your server room (as indicated by the motion sensor), will running Revelation on your machine prevent you from losing money and reputation?

Comment: Nice to see someone else here is playing Uplink!  While it may be a plausible substitute (I'm not sure it would actually work), the self-destruct device would be much faster if you keep it running in the background.  You can run the self-destruct, and trim it down to almost no CPU usage until such time as it is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will, however it also spreads to other systems (apart from the first version), so if you're going for the good ending I'd advise against it.

From an [Uplink forum post](http://forums.introversion.co.uk/uplink/viewtopic.php?t=38340):

> Q: I activated Revelation on my computer, how do I get it back???
>   A: Smart move. Well, you can't get it back - you have just ruined it. However, all your information is there - the account, the rating.
>   So you just have to buy a new computer, and buy again all your
>   hardware and software. Could be worse, however...

Comment: The *first* version of Revelation doesn't spread. This makes it perfect for those "destroy a system" missions.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen I did not know that, edited in.

Comment: Yes, Revelation v.1 and self destruct are functionally equivalent. This is very useful with the computer with only one security slot!